# Can I Install Ubuntu on ATIV BOOK 4

Tags: dual-boot

My Laptop is Samsung ATIV BOOK 4 NP450R4V-XO2, Can I Install Ubuntu On My Laptop Dual Boot With Windows 7,if Can, Please Give me Information For Install That?

Answer (score 0):

You can try ubuntu on separate partition other than your windows one.Remaining process is same as installation of ubuntu on Complete HDD.There are various blogs and websites to guide you step-by step installation. Official one is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

All the Best !